# Нет причин для постановки запятой ― это можно считать ответом?

Tags: обсуждение

Я считаю, что это **неполноценный ответ без объяснения** и постараюсь доказать это.

**Неправильное объяснение:** запятая не ставится, потому что в этом предложении  нет причин для постановки запятой.

**Правильное объяснение:** запятая не ставится, потому что это предложение является простым неосложненным  предложением.

**А как это доказать?** Для этого надо знать структуру простых, сложных и осложненных предложений, причем особенное внимание следует уделить именно простому предложению.

**1) О простом предложении**

Х**мурившаяся с утра погода / начала разъясняться.**
Это простое предложение тем не менее имеет сложную  интонационную структуру, а именно: фраза восходящего тона – короткая пауза (перелом интонации) – фраза нисходящего тона. Данная интонационная форма воспринимается как стандартная, поэтому **знаки препинания в простом предложении отсутствуют.**

**А вот паузы присутствуют:**  (1) Переход из одной тональности в другую может восприниматься как пауза. (2) В распространенном предложении делаются дополнительные  произносительные паузы:  В июльские вечера (пауза)  опьяняющий медвяный запах липы (пауза, повышение тона)  поглощает все другие запахи города (понижение тона).

Наличие нескольких пауз в распространенном простом предложении часто приводит  к тому, что их на письме обозначают запятыми,  что является ошибкой. **Не каждая пауза обозначается запятой, а только грамматически обоснованная.**

2) Таким образом, отвечая на вопрос, мы **должны доказать, что  в  данном предложении нет однородных  и обособленных членов и оно не является сложным (содержащим несколько предикативных основ)**. Следует учесть, что иногда  структура предложения позволяет перейти к обособленному варианту безо всякой перестройки (авторское обособление): Чаадаев находился в центре внимания мыслящей – и одновременно немыслимой – России. Коля Иволгин, по отъезде князя, сначала продолжал свою прежнюю жизнь. Видно, и Чичиковы, на несколько минут в жизни, обращаются в поэтов .

3) **Итак, автор вопроса хочет поставить запятую,  а почему?**  Возможно, его смущает наличие паузы или он считает, что в предложение входят обособленные члены. Или он еще что-то считает. **Если вы поняли, в чем дело, то у вас есть шанс дать грамотный ответ, который решит поставленную проблему.**

Comment: Вопросы, касающиеся работы форума и модерирования, следует размещать на https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

> Любой ответ, который направляет спрашивающего в нужное русло, является ценным. Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. Изложите свои предложения. Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше.

Продолжение — в [Справке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Наверняка вы заметили, что у сообщений нередко появляются плашки, в которых даются рекомендации о том, как стоит доработать ответы. Действительно, если ответ не содержит обоснований, либо ссылки на источник, либо в нем изложена совершенно не очевидная информация, — скорее всего, он будет удален через некоторое время после предупреждения, так как в противном случае он может ввести автора вопроса в заблуждение.

Если вы видите некачественные сообщения, обязательно отмечайте их тревогой "Необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством", а также не забывайте просматривать ["Очередь проверок"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/review).

Answer (score 2):

Мне нравится краткий и понятный ответ "Нет причин (условий) для постановки запятой". Запятая действительно ставится "по причине" или "при условии", а если таковых нет, то и запятая не нужна. Ответ корректный.

Comment: А как определить, что нет причин и условий?  В предыдущей теме было местоименное слово КОТОРЫЙ, а оно не так часто встречается в середине предложения, поэтому было бы неплохо что-нибудь сказать по этому поводу. Думаю, что именно местоимение и  было причиной вопроса о запятой,  а информацию о нем можно было найти  в словаре.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ может считаться верным или неверным по ряду причин.  Верный а) если автора интересует только ответ "да" или "нет",б) смотря, кто дает ответ и кто задает вопрос. Постоянные участники форума знают друг друга и, соответственно, знают кому доверять, а кому нет.  б)неправильный.Здесь ответ может дать любой, кому это вздумается.  И ответ может может оказаться неверным, и, если, участник -  новичок может поверить ответу. Если здесь отвечали бы на вопросы только лингвисты-филологи, как, например,на Грамоте.ру, то такой ответ стоило бы признать правильным в любом случае. Поэтому в любом случае лучше кратко объяснить причину отсутствия запятой.

Comment: Серж, Вы меня не поняли. Я хотела спросить: это вообще можно считать ответом? Диалог такой: Надо ставить запятую? - Нет, не надо. Ответ верный, но безо ВСЯКИХ ОБЪЯСНЕНИЙ. При этом отвечающий считает,  что объяснять надо постановку запятой, а отсутствие запятой объяснять не надо. А я считаю, что при ответе надо ДОКАЗАТЬ, что это простое нераспространенное предложение. В противном случае это неполноценный ответ, вряд ли  ему место на форуме.  Впрочем, вопрос дискуссионный.

Comment: Sibylla, я вас понял. Поэтому у написал: это зависит от ряда причин.

Comment: Хотя надо учитывать и правила форума - здесь приняты развернутые ответы.

Comment: Дело не только в правилах форума, здесь вопрос принципиальный. Вот перед Вами развернутое предложение (5- 6 слов), Вы смотрите на него и говорите: запятую не ставим, потому что нет оснований для постановки запятых.  Но ведь вы можете это утверждать только в том случае, если уверены, что предложение простое неосложненное,  а это совсем не очевидно. Значит, отсутствие запятых тоже надо доказывать? Или нет?

Comment: "Здесь приняты развернутые ответы" – это чтобы себя показать? Кем приняты?

Comment: У модераторов спросите, они Вам объяснят.

Comment: Для кого не очевидно, Sybilla? Для кого не очевидно то простое предложение? Если для кого-то не очевидно, то он уж заведомо не поймет и ваших "тонов".

Comment: Niemand, нет, не чтобы себя показать, а для того, чтобы ответ был ясен.  Здесь никто себя не показывает.  И, к тому же, зачем должны участники на слово нам верить?

Comment: Но "Грамоте" верят же?.. Я к чему волоку: "развернутые ответы" от дилетантов выглядят, как бы это сказать... слегка смешно. Ну, в большинстве случаев. Или вы не согласны?

Comment: Почему смешно? Если  вы,например, дадите ответ и сошлетесь на правило, что тут смешного?

Comment: Сошлитесь на правило, по которому в "мама мыла раму" никаких знаков не требуется.

Comment: Здесь можно объяснить,что это простое предложение, не осложненное ничем.

Comment: Согласитесь, если случаи,когда отвечающий может не увидеть нужной запятой, и ответить,что запятая не нужна, а ответ окажется неверным.

Comment: Согласитесь, что это не наш случай.

Comment: В данном случае да. Я же не имею в виду вас. Я говорю в общем.